# get active ul li element id by clicking another ul li element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two `ul` elements. On clicking either I want to get both the active `li` element's class. Right now I am getting only one active `li` element class by clicking any `ul` element.

```
<div class="container secondary-header-tab-container">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs header-tabs dashboard-tabs" id="tab-shift" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active">
            <a href="#" aria-controls="active" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="filter active" data-filter=".filterActive" id="active">Active</a>
            <p class="active_jobs_count" data-count="">0</p>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="">
            <a href="#" aria-controls="archived" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="filter" data-filter=".filterArchived" id="inactive">Inactive</a>
            <p class="active_jobs_count" data-count="">0</p>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="">
            <a href="#" aria-controls="completed" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" class="filter" data-filter=".filterCompleted" id="closed">Closed</a>
            <p class="active_jobs_count" data-count="">0</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="job-card-sort-container pull-right" title="Filter">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle active-sort" data-toggle="dropdown"  aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">All</button>
            <div type="button" class="btn btn-default sort-dropdown-icon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
            </div>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#" class="filter active" data-filter="all">All</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".normal" >Normal</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".urgent" >Urgent</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".private">Private</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="filter" data-filter=".shared" >Shared</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.dashboard-tabs li, .job-card-sort-container ul li', function() {
    var dataFilter = $('.secondary-header-tab-container').find('.dashboard-tabs li .active').text();
    alert(dataFilter);
    var job_type = $('.secondary-header-tab-container').find('.job-card-sort-container ul li .active').text();
    alert(job_type);
});
```

Comment: Facing same issue can any one suggest best answer. Thanks

Comment: I created a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pvwxh90j/ and it alerts both of the active  <li>s. Not sure what you're asking

Comment: thanks @Steve. Assume ul1 and ul2, ul1 has 3 li and ul2 has 5 li on page loading ul1.li1 and ul2.li1 is active. Now if i click ul2.li2, the active class from ul2.li1 should be removed and added to newly clicked li element i.e., ul2.li2 now my question is at the same time i want two alert message 1. ul2.li2 id and 2. ul1.li1 id (because ul1.li1 is still active right). Similarly if i click ul1.li3(or)li2 trigger alert message ul.li(3 or 2) id and ul2.li2 id.

Comment: In the above comment id means it may be a data-filter or text()

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/pvwxh90j/1/ This has the change I think you're looking for.

Comment: @Steve thank you so much, its working fine.